# ¿Cómo reducir el tiempo de ejecución de mi consulta?

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle-11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

Tengo un problema de una sentencia SQL, lo que pasa es que tarda mucho en recuperar la información y quería ver si me pueden ayudar a optimizar la misma:

```
SELECT  cast(cd_ITVALCNV as VARCHAR(6)) AS cd_ITVALCNV, 
    cd_ICTTO, 
    cast(cd_IEMISORA as VARCHAR(8)) AS cd_IEMISORA,
    cast(cd_ISERIE as VARCHAR(8)) AS cd_ISERIE,
    cd_ICUPON, 
    cd_ISUBFOL, 
    cd_IFOLADM, 
    cast(nb_SORIMOV as VARCHAR(2)) AS nb_SORIMOV, 
    cd_FOPERA, 
    im_CTITEXI 
    FROM (SELECT    cd_ITVALCNV, 
            cd_ICTTO, 
            cd_IEMISORA, 
            cd_ISERIE, 
            cd_ICUPON, 
            cd_ISUBFOL, 
            cd_IFOLADM,
            nb_SORIMOV, 
            FN_MAXFOPERA(cd_ITVALCNV, cd_ICTTO, cd_IEMISORA, cd_ISERIE, cd_ICUPON, cd_ISUBFOL, cd_IFOLADM, nb_SORIMOV) as cd_FOPERA, 
            FN_LASTCTITEXI(cd_ITVALCNV, cd_ICTTO, cd_IEMISORA, cd_ISERIE, cd_ICUPON, cd_ISUBFOL, cd_IFOLADM, nb_SORIMOV, 
                    FN_MAXFOPERA(cd_ITVALCNV, cd_ICTTO, cd_IEMISORA, cd_ISERIE, cd_ICUPON, cd_ISUBFOL, cd_IFOLADM, nb_SORIMOV)
                    ) AS im_CTITEXI  
            FROM (SELECT DISTINCT   cd_ITVALCNV, cd_ICTTO, cd_IEMISORA, cd_ISERIE, 
                            cd_ICUPON,cd_ISUBFOL, 
                        CASE WHEN nb_SORIMOV = 'RP' 
                            THEN FN_MAXIFOLADM(cd_ITVALCNV, cd_ICTTO, cd_IEMISORA, cd_ISERIE, cd_ICUPON, cd_ISUBFOL, nb_SORIMOV) 
                            ELSE cd_IFOLADM 
                        END AS cd_IFOLADM, 
                        nb_SORIMOV 
                        FROM TVIV023_KARCAS KC  
                        WHERE cd_ISUBFOL <> 4
                )
        ) 
        WHERE im_CTITEXI <> 0
```

Entre esos también invocan funciones, que la verdad no se mucho de bases de datos, las funciones son:

```
create or replace FUNCTION FN_MAXFOPERA (V_itvalcnv IN CHAR,
                              V_ictto    IN NUMBER,
                              V_iemisora IN CHAR,
                              V_iserie   IN CHAR,
                              V_icupon   IN NUMBER,
                              V_isubfol  IN NUMBER,
                              V_ifoladm  IN NUMBER,
                              V_sorimov  IN CHAR)
RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
v_fopera TVIV023_KARCAS.cd_FOPERA%TYPE;
BEGIN
  SELECT Max(cd_FOPERA)
  INTO v_fopera
  FROM TVIV023_KARCAS K
  WHERE K.cd_ITVALCNV = V_itvalcnv 
    AND K.cd_ICTTO    = V_ictto    
    AND K.cd_IEMISORA = V_iemisora 
    AND K.cd_ISERIE   = V_iserie   
    AND K.cd_ICUPON   = V_icupon   
    AND K.cd_ISUBFOL  = V_isubfol
    AND K.cd_IFOLADM  = V_ifoladm
    AND K.nb_SORIMOV  = V_sorimov;
  RETURN v_fopera;
END;
```

Por ejemplo, si hay alguna manera de sacar las funciones de ese query y convertirlas en consultas.

Espero y me puedan ayudar, estas sentencias como tal, yo no las cree, solo me pidieron que quitara ese query y cree otro y este mas optimizado que la verdad no tengo idea de como empezar.

Comment: Podrías construir un procedimiento almacenado que abarque esos dos select anidados y te devuelva una tabla temporal y procesarla como quieras. O bien ir creando en la misma consulta las tablas temporales.

Comment: Hola buenas tardes, perdon por la demora en responder, como podria implementar esta solucion que mencionas? desafortunadamente no se mucho de bd :( pero estoy dispuesto a aprenderlo